# Desplegar radio button en django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Hola tengo este inconveniente ... no puedo lograr desplegar en la plantilla los radio button ... en que me equivoco ?

**models.py**

```
class Genero(models.Model):

    MASCULINO ='mas'

    FEMENINO ='fem'
    Type_CHOICES = (
    (MASCULINO,'masculino'),
    (FEMENINO,'femenino'))
    sexo = models.CharField(choices=Type_CHOICES,default=MASCULINO, max_length=100)
```

**form.py**

```
class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=Genero
        fields=['sexo']
        widgets = {
        'sexo': forms.RadioSelect(choices=Video.Type_CHOICES)           

}
```

**template**

```
{% for radio in sexo %}

    <label >
        {{ radio }}
        <span> {{ radio.tag }} </span>
    </label>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para el formulario no hace falta iterar sobre sus opciones, basta con poner

```
{{ sexo }}
```

Aunque me suena raro que pases directamente la variable así, no debería ser por ejemplo:

```
{{ form.sexo }}
```